# IndexError when I try to fill a list of lists from a multidimensional numpy array with expression statement in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, math

Starting from a csv file, I have a multidimensional numpy array (dimensions: 617 x 9) and I need only one column of that n x m array. In that column are stored sequential data like the following:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,620,625,622,710,658,2150,2142,2569,2600,21,24,30,45,32,14,1100,1119,1150 ...]
```

In a more or less cyclic manner these represent sets of values that are not very dissimilar to each other. I would need to assign the averages and the standard deviation of these values to a list. So in the specific example we will have (I will just calculate the mean sorry):

```
[0, 647.0, 2365.25, 27.67, 1126.33, ...]
```

I'm not very skilled with python, so what I thought is to fill a list of lists with those values for which there is a difference of 200 between the nth and the next n+1 and then work with it, like:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0], [620,625,622,710,658], [2150,2142,2569,2600], [21,24,30,45,32,14], [1100,1119,1150] ...]
```

My beginner code is this:

```
import numpy as np
import os, time, argparse, matplotlib, glob, datetime, sys, math
path = "/path_to_file/file.csv"
data = np.loadtxt(data, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

x = [[]]
n_entries = len(data[:,0])
count = 0
m = 0

for n in range(n_entries-1):
    if (math.isclose(data[n,1], data[n+1,1], abs_tol = 200)):
        x[count][m] = data[n,1]
        m += 1

    else:
        count += 1
        m = 0
```

Unfortunately I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path_to_python_file/file.py", line 49, in <module>
    x[count][m] = data[n,1]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

First, I would love to have an explanation to the error, even though, diving around the net, I'm feeling like I have to initialize the list before...but actually I don't really know in principle its dimensions. Second, I would appreciate any advice on other ways to do that if someone feels smarter than me!

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You can't create new elements in a list by assigning to the index. Use `.append()`

Comment: Why are you using lists? Make `x` a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Barmar! Your advice has been enlightening! I will post the answer just in case someone in the future will need it quickly! For sure there will be a more elegant way to do it but it works fine!

```
import statistics as st
import numpy as np
import math

def cyclic_values_finder(array,value):
    m_crutch = []
    m = 0
    for n in range(n_entries-1):
        if not (math.isclose(array[n,value], array[n+1,value], abs_tol = 200)):
            m_crutch.append(n+1)
    m_crutch.append(n_entries)
    return m_crutch

def get_array_values(array, value):
    arr = []
    for ii in range(n_entries):
        arr.append(array[ii,value]) 
    return arr

n = 1      # whatever columns of data you'll need to process
path = "/path_to_file/file.csv"
data = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
data_needed = get_array_values(data,n)
n_rows = np.array(cyclic_values_finder(data,n))

splitted_data = np.split(data_needed)

avg = []
stdev = []
for row in splitted_data :
    avg.append(st.mean(row))
    stdev.append(st.stdev(row))
```